# How to swap jquery for prototype in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, prototypejs

I have a rails 3.1 project that was created with the default jQuery.  What is the best way to convert the project to use prototype instead?

Comment: That's like asking to go from PHP to ASP. The best way is to re-write the code.

Comment: I'm not asking how to rewrite the jQuery code to use prototype. Just how to change the rails environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Remove the jquery gem from Gemfile
2. add prototype-rails to it

From https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails:

> You may want to add them to your
>   app/assets/javascripts/application.js:
>
> ```
> //= require prototype
> //= require prototype_ujs
> //= require effects
> //= require dragdrop
> //= require controls
> ```
>
> New applications using this may also want to add
>
> ```
> config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
> ```
>
> to their config/environments/development.rb.

Comment: Thanks.  This works, except that config.action_view.debug_rjs has been [removed](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default) from rails 3.1

Comment: @DavidNehme I thought the same thing at first, but the prototype-rails description on github says "Add RJS, Prototype, and Scriptaculous helpers to Rails 3.1+ apps".

Comment: I didn't know Rails had a js framework abstraction layer. Hmmm.

Comment: @Diodeus yes, but it's very lightweight. "Unobtrusive", as it were. Yes, I know this is an old comment ;)

Answer (score -3):

diodeus is right, i'd rewrite it, and take it as a great opportunity to improve the code ;)
nevertheless i'm curious, why would you wanna switch TO prototype