# rails observe_form and prototype: return '$A($(form).getElementsByTagName('*'))'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, ruby-on-rails-2, updating, rjs

I have observe_form in my view:

`<%= observe_form 'new_lead', :url => { :action => 'update_price' }, :frequency => 0.1 %>`
, _update_price.rjs partial and this method in controller:

```
      def update_price
        unless request.xhr?
          redirect_to :controller => 'index'
        else
          set_price_group

          render :partial => "update_price", 
                 :locals  => { :services => params[:service], 
                               :spectr   => params[:spectr]   }
        end
      end
```

I'm upgrading rails_2 app to rails_3. 
On rails_2 it's no errors, but when I upgrade project to rails3
I have javascript error in 3484 line of prototype.js:
"$(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function ".

```
       getElements: function(form) {
        return $A($(form).getElementsByTagName('*')).inject([],
        function(elements, child) {
          if (Form.Element.Serializers[child.tagName.toLowerCase()])
            elements.push(Element.extend(child));
          return elements;
        }
       );},
```

And 'update_price' does not calling periodically.
I don't know is it problem related to rails upgrading or just problem with JS :(
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3.1 uses jQuery instead of Prototypejs. You can get back the prototype functionality by using something like https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails

Related [How to swap jquery for prototype in Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534122/how-to-swap-jquery-for-prototype-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

Than if somebody have an error:

```
    TypeError: document.on is not a function
```

Changing prototype.js 1.6.x to 1.7 will solve it ;)