# Javascript to remove nested fields throws error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a noob to Rails and Javascript. I've made an app with nested attributes while following Ryan Bates' Railscasts [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) & [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) (Nested Model Forms).

Everything works fine upto the point where I use Checkboxes to remove fields. But when I use this in my _question_fields.html.erb:

`<%= link_to_function 'remove', 'remove_fields(this)' %>`

and this javascript function in /assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
  $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}
```

nothing happens. I've made sure that `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` is being included in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Javascript Consoles on Firefox (Firebug) & Chrome (Built-in) throw this error when I click on the remove link.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Am I missing something very basic? Any help would be appreciated. I'm Using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3 & Mongoid 3.1.2.

Comment: Did you forget to link Prototype, maybe? The error indicates so.

Comment: It's a javascript framework used by RoR. `$` and stuff like `.previous` and `.up` belong to it. http://prototypejs.org/

Comment: Well, I've added the prototype-rails gem (following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7534515/1533054)) but still nothing happens. This time, javascript console throws "Object has no method 'previous' "

Comment: I added the //=require prototype ... code in application.js and now the page doesn't display. It says "Sprockets::FileNotFound" and  "couldn't find file 'prototype'"

Comment: @bfavaretto - Okay, so I included both gems, 'jquery-rails' and 'prototype-rails' and commented out `config.action_view.debug_rjs = true` and it's working now. Please post your solution as an answer so I can mark this question resolved....

Comment: Thanks, but I don't feel comfortable to add an answer as I wouldn't be able to provide more details (not really familiar with RoR). Maybe you could add your own answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution (as pointed out by [bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773749/javascript-to-remove-nested-fields-throws-error?noredirect=1#comment22422859_15773749)) was simple enough. We need to use the `prototype` gem and add it's reference in `application.js`.

**1) In your `Gemfile`, add:**

```
gem 'prototype-rails'
# You might want to comment out #gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**2) In `application.js`, above everything else, add:**

```
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
```

**3) Make sure this line is removed/commented in `config/enviroments/development.rb`:**

```
#config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

**4) Run Bundler and restart Rails Server**

```
$ bundle install
$ rails s         # This is important!
```